# We stand at an inflection point in history

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Joe Biden tweeted:

> United States government official
> **We stand at an inflection point in history**. The United States intends to work with partners and allies to answer these questions and help lead the world toward a more peaceful, prosperous future for all people.

Source: [Twitter:Joe Biden](https://twitter.com/JoeBiden)

I understand "We stand at **an inflection point** in history" as "We stand at **a turning point** in history." Am I on the right track?

Comment: Is there anything in the [dictionary meaning](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inflection%20point) that you don't understand?

Comment: Interestingly, the term "inflection point" doesn't yet exist in the full OED (although "point of inflection" is mentioned under "inflection" - only in its mathematical sense), but it is in smaller works (which get updated more regularly).

Comment: @rjpond:  "inflection point"  may not be explicitly *defined* in the OED, but it occurs in their first cited use of the term **yellowcake** - *The occurrence of an **inflection point** on the pH versus acid addition curve defines the complete precipitation of the sodium uranyl vanadate or yellow cake.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an expression I'm familiar with (probably because I'm British), but I understood it the same way as you did (i.e. as meaning "turning point"), and [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/inflection_point) confirms that we are both correct:

> *US* (in business) a time of significant change in a situation; a turning point.

("Inflection point" has two definitions, one a specialised one in mathematics, the other the American one above, which Lexico associates with the business world.)

The term is also defined by [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inflection%20point):

> a moment when significant change occurs or may occur : turning point